# WSDL web service returns old data from database even if I have updated the database

Tags: java, php, database, jpa, eclipselink

I have a web service that is running and generates a WSDL file based on data that is stored on the database.

When I update some columns in the database with new data and then reloads the WSDL, the old value is still returned from the web service.

Do I have to enable somthing on the `EntityManager` (in the java code) or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do you really mean **WSDL**? I can hardly imagine a system that changes the WSDL (web service contract, in other words interface description) upon change in the database (although of course it is possible).

That being said I assume it is the web service response that changes. Looks like you are using JPA. Most JPA providers add some caching layer. E.g. in Hibernate there is L1 cache, L2 and query cache. If you are modifying the database manually, JPA has no knowledge about these changes and still serves old data.

Please specify which JPA provider you use, typically there is a way to manually flush caches (either in the provider or in the caching library).

UPDATE: It turned out you are using EclipseLink. Please try clearing the cache with the following code:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaHelper.
  getEntityManager(entityManager).
  getEntityManagerFactory().
  getCache().
  evictAll();
```

Now the tricky part - **when to call it?** The best solution is to execute this functionality every time you modify the database directly. You mentioned it is the PHP scripts that modifies the database directly. Calling Java from PHP can be achieved e.g. with JMX and [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) or you can expose yet another SOAP web service.

Another solution is to clear cache periodically if you can live with stale data for a while. On the other hand clearing the cache on every update might be a performance killer.

Comment: Yes, JPA is beeing used (EclipseLink JPA). The WSDL file itself is not beeing changed upon changes in database, it is just that the web service do not get the new data. The database is beeing updated manually (or at least it is not the web service that updates the database, it is php code that updates it).

Comment: @Rox: JPA, but what provider? Hibernater? EclipseLink? OpenJPA? You either have to disable caching or force cache invalidation in your PHP script (tricky Java-PHP integration). Almost for sure if you restart your application, it will return new data.

Comment: Sorry, EclipseLink (edited my previous comment 10 secs ago) :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I added that line in a get method (a method that reads from database) and it worked! Now the new data displays everytime I update the database. Is it a good practice to do so on every method that gets data from database?

Comment: @Rox: no, **it is not** a good idea. It defeats the purpose of caching, effectively slowing your application down, because the cache is still updated by JPA, but never really used. You should call this method on every raw database **update** (update through JPA automatically refresh caches) or periodically.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is better to have that line in the methods that update the database. I will create such methods that update the database in my web service and clear the cache in those methods. The PHP solution was just temporary. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to disable caching behaviour of EclipseLink by adding following line to your persistence.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="NONE" />
```